# Css is correctly working on Local but not on server Django?

Tags: python, css, django, server

CSS is Loading perfectly on local but not on the server.
Also, I am trying using static_root and collectstatic method but that way the CSS is loading totally.

Comment: Django doesn't serve static files in production. You need to use a server like NGINX or Apache or a CDN to serve them.

Comment: Pls Helping Link

Comment: Google it. I don't know which server you're using.

Comment: I am using Ngnix Server

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04 . Look for the NGINX configuration. It's on the later part of the tutorial.

Comment: Doing Server using already this link